# Data validation between SQL replicated tables

Tags: sql-server, replication, validation

I am trying to figure out a way to validate the data in my publisher and subscriber in SQL 2005 replication. I thought of using sp_publication_validation, but it needs db_owner permission and we are not allowed to have it in our company.

So I did bit more reading and found out about two other SPs that I think work for me.

First one is sp_article_validation, which I plan to run on the publisher. For each article that I call this SP, its gonna give the row count and a checksum. With that info, I intend to call sp_table_validation on the subscriber, passing the row count and checksum from the previous SP, there by validating both tables.

What do you guys think? Is this a proven way to validate data in replication? There is very little documentation on these SPs. Here is the link:

sp_table_validation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239370(v=sql.80).aspx
sp_article_validation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177511(v=SQL.90).aspx

Thanks for taking a look at this post

Vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation from Books Online regarging [Validating Replicated Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152758.aspx)

Personally I prefer to use the [tablediff utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx)

Comment: I have to do this check from a batch file which connects to the sql server under an application account. In our company, these application accounts wont be given db_owner access. All the techniqies mentioned in the above document needs db_owner. So I am looking at other options.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to perform this validation? The validity of a Replication topology should be ensured through appropriate solution design.

Comment: We had a scenario once when some one accidentally deleted the transaction logs on the publisher. We realised this only after users complained about the data mismatch. So I am working on preventing this from happening again and to ensure that we (development) are the first ones to know if there is a break.